# How to write this json string as param in python command line?

Tags: python, json

I'm writing qemu qga command through python script like this:

```
python cmd.py request:'{"execute": "guest-execute", "session": "4768", "arguments": {"commands": [{"command": "/bin/sh", "arguments": ["sh", "-c", "route | grep default | awk '{print $2}'"]}]}}'
```

but the param is parsed into bellow, which devide json string from '{print $2}' :

```
['cmd.py', 'request:{"execute": "guest-execute", "session": "4768", "arguments": {"commands": [{"command": "/bin/sh", "arguments": ["sh", "-c", "route | grep default | awk {print', '}"]}]}}']
```

actually I want this, which `awk {print'{print $2}'` is shell command running in vm, and this format could not change:

```
['cmd.py', 'request:{"execute": "guest-execute", "session": "4768", "arguments": {"commands": [{"command": "/bin/sh", "arguments": ["sh", "-c", "route | grep default | awk {print'{print $2}'}"]}]}}']
```

Is it possible? If it's impossible, it means I have to construct json string by hand in cmd.py?

Thank you~

Comment: You have to remove spaces and use backslash for your quotes. This way, your entire json string will be seen as just one argument.

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally embedded single quotes in other single quotes:
If I leave out the first part of the string you get the following:

`request:'... | awk '{print $2}'"]}]}}'`

Which the shell sees as three parts, and tries to resolve the `$2` there:

`request:'... | awk '` `{print $2}` `'"]}]}}'`

If you want to embed single quotes in other single quotes, you have to do it like this:

`echo 'This string contains '\'' <- an embedded quote'`

So in your case the full command should be

`python cmd.py request:'{"execute": "guest-execute", "session": "4768", "arguments": {"commands": [{"command": "/bin/sh", "arguments": ["sh", "-c", "route | grep default | awk '\''{print $2}'\''"]}]}}'`